# Bootstrap autocomplete is not working in webstorm

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have added as dependencies  in package.json :

```
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
```

2. updated in the angular-cli.json file to the styles

   "styles": [
         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "styles.css"
3. ng_modules folder has the configured bootstrap module.
4. installed the emmetEverywhere for the auto completion as a plugin.

but still in my app.component.html I could not do the auto completion.

Am I missing something in the configurations?

Comment: good job, now Try to download it directly not with npm

Comment: @maher Am very sorry,  I dint get what you are  saying.I just downloaded the bootstrap from their official site. Now how  do I move forward from here  ?

Comment: ok, 1: set your js and css in your index, 2: inject external module if exist in your app,  3: test it, do not forget to add jQuery before bootstrap.js, for more inforation [Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: Still Webstorm is not able to detect '.' and give me suggestions in component html.  But seems to working fine in the webpages though.

Comment: same problem, no autocomplete for bootstrap in webstorm

Comment: @FaizanShakeel did you add bootstrap js dependency ?

Comment: yes, bootstrap functionality is there, I have no problem except that there's no auto complete for bootstrap, im using accordion also which needs bootstrap js, so thats there but no auto complete :S